# In bash, how can I print the first n elements of a list?

Tags: bash, syntax

In `bash`, how can I print the first `n` elements of a list?

For example, the first 10 files in this list:

```
FILES=$(ls)
```

**UPDATE:** I forgot to say that I want to print the elements on one line, just like when you print the whole list with `echo $FILES`.

Comment: I made a small correction to my solution. It should print all filenames on one line. Did you try it?

Comment: Please read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- It's important you understand the intricacies and pitfalls of bash if you want to avoid disasters on your files.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
FILES=(*)
echo "${FILES[@]:0:10}"
```

Should work correctly even if there are spaces in filenames.

`FILES=$(ls)` creates a string variable. `FILES=(*)` creates an array. See this page for more [examples on using arrays in bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays). (thanks lhunath)

Comment: No, it prints the first 10 elements of an array. The array contains filenames as items.

Comment: Your reference to the ABS is bad.  They don't use quotes (typical ABS), thus causing wordsplitting bugs on the expanded filename.  ABS is full of such hidden bugs causing anyone who learns from it (except for you, apparantly, you do it right) to inherit those bugs!  I'd refer to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TheBasics/Arrays instead.

Comment: ABS contains a wealth of useful information in my opinion. But in this case, the link you provided is more relevant so I added it to my answer.

Comment: You should be more clear on FILE=(*); maybe use the original command sub: FILES=($(ls))

Comment: @guns, why spawn an `ls` process when you can use globbing?

Comment: @guns: That also doesn't do the right thing when the filenames contain spaces.

Answer (score 11):

Why not just this to print the first 50 files:

```
ls -1 | head -50
```

Comment: OP wanted it printed on one line. See comments.

Comment: @kubanczyk it becomes:  ls -1 | head -50  | tr '\n' ' '

Answer (score 6):

```
FILE="$(ls | head -1)"
```

Handled spaces in filenames correctly too when I tried it.

Comment: This can give you multiple directories. Perhaps you mean `$(ls -1 | head -1)`?

Answer (score 4):

My way would be:

```
ls | head -10 | tr "\n" " "
```

This will print the first 10 lines returned by ls, and then tr replaces all line breaks with spaces. Output will be on a single line.

Comment: Nice answer. I maybe you should also add `-1` such as `ls -1 | head -10 | tr "\n" " "`. In any case this is what I was looking for ;)

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.  Nice and simple.  List them.  Select the first 10.  Strip out newlines for spaces.  Done and done.  Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $FILES | awk '{for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {print $i}}'
```

Edit: AAh, missed your comment that you needed them on one line...

```
echo $FILES | awk '{for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {printf "%s ", $i}}'
```

That one does that.

Answer (score 1):

to do it interactively:

`set $FILES && eval eval echo \\\${1..10}`

to run it as a script, create foo.sh with contents

`N=$1; shift; eval eval echo \\\${1..$N}`

and run it as

`bash foo.sh 10 $FILES`

Answer (score 1):

An addition to the answer of "Ayman Hourieh" and "Shawn Chin", in case it is needed for something else than content of a directory.

In newer version of bash you can use mapfile to store the directory in an array. See `help mapfile`

```
mapfile -t files_in_dir < <( ls )
```

If you want it completely in bash use `printf "%s\n" *` instead of `ls`, or just replace `ls` with any other command you need.

Now you can access the array as usual and get the data you need.

First element:

```
${files_in_dir[0]}
```

Last element (do not forget space after ":" ):

```
${files_in_dir[@]: -1}
```

Range e.g. from 10 to 20:

```
${files_in_dir[@]:10:20}
```

**Attention for large directories**, this is way more memory consuming than the other solutions.

Comment: This actually answers the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILES=$(ls)
echo $FILES | fmt -1 | head -10
```

Comment: Does not work as expected if there are files with spaces in their names.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but thought dehmann wanted to use this specific method, so I reckoned spaces wouldn't be a problem.

BTW, did you mean

FILES=(*)
echo "${FILES[@]:0:10}"

? That works better here.