# How to read first n elements from array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops

```
sum=0
read n
read -a array

      for i in "${array[@]}" 
      do 
      sum=$(( $sum + $i ))  
      done 

echo $sum
```

I am new in scripting. Here I want to know what can I use to add condition so that reading array will be limited to n times.

Ex:

```
3
1 2 3 4
```

here it should add only 1 2 3 and it should not take 4.

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885620/in-bash-how-can-i-print-the-first-n-elements-of-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the bash C for loop, it doesn't require conditionals to escape the loop and looks neater.

```
#! /bin/bash

sum=0

read n
read -a array

for ((x=0; x<n; x++))
do
    sum=$(( sum + array[x] ))
done

echo "$sum"
```

Comment: In the context of the question I think you can infer that n is the number of elements you want to step through the array. We should also validate n is a number, n<{#array[@]}, {array[n]} is a number, but simple question, simple answer

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the loop altogether and use parameter substitution for slicing the array like this:

```
$ cat script.bash 
sum=0
read -p "Enter n: " n
read -p "Enter space separated array elements: " -a array
echo "${array[@]:0:$n}" | sed 's/\s/+/g' | bc
$ ./script.bash 
Enter n: 3
Enter space separated array elements: 1 2 3 4
6
$
```

`echo "${array[@]:0:$n}" | sed 's/\s/+/g' | bc` this statement dynamically slices the array and substitutes space `\s` with `+` to form the addition expression which is then piped to `bc` (calculator)

Answer (score 1):

```
sum=0
i=0
read n
read -a array

    while [[ $i -lt $n ]]                                        
  do 
      sum=$(( $sum + ${array[$i]}))
      let i++ 
   done 

echo $sum
```

I tried this and it worked. In btw thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

sum=0
read n
j=0
read -a array

```
  for i in "${array[@]}"
  do
  if [[ $j -ge $n ]];then
    break
  else
  sum=$(( $sum + $i ))
  (( j = j + 1 ))
    fi
  done
```

echo $sum

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
param=$1
sum=0

for i in {0..$param}
do
let " sum = $sum + ${array[$i]} "
done

echo "RESULT: $sum"
```

and execute

```
./scipt.sh n
```